# What are the disadvantages of storing cookies in a database instead of a file?

Tags: php, curl, cookies, amazon-efs

I am working on a service that sits between a client and an API. A client user does API requests via my service. The API requires several user cookies to be set to authenticate the user and allow requests. The client cannot store cookies, so I am storing all the cookies on AWS EFS. The service is written in PHP and API requests are done using cURL. Cookie handling is done using cURL's `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`.

The problem is that sometimes the cookie file gets overwritten instead of appended to or updated, leading to API requests failing. I am still trying to find the cause of this, but I am considering saving the cookies to the database instead of in a file. Obviously this will lead to an increased database load, but I cannot think of any other disadvantages. Are there any?

Comment: being a cookie here is a red herring, there is a problem with your file read-write code and you want to fix it by using a database instead,. I would want to fix the file-read-write first personally. Not saying that using a db might be better anyway

Comment: *"Obviously this will lead to an increased database load"* - What numbers are we talking here and is this on a daily / continuous basis 24/7?

Comment: @Dagon Thanks, I'm still looking into the cause of the issue. The problem is that I don't have any file read-write code. I am using `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` that take care of reading from and writing to the cookie files. I would expect such a widely used library as PHP cURL to handle this correctly and therefore am a weary of starting to write my own code for this. I have searched if there is a known problem with PHP cURL, but couldn't find anything. Maybe the problem is in the combination of AWS EFS and PHP cURL. It's not happening consistently, so it's difficult to debug.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, it's on a continuous 24/7 basis. I cannot say how many consecutive users, but it's a fairly large number.

Comment: @Mischa databases can handle rather a large load, I don't foresee a problem in using a db. Just as long as there's PK with maybe an added UNIQUE constraint set to the cookie column.